# How to keep the previous html 5 video on a different canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video, webcam-capture

Here is the situation.

I'm trying to create thumbnails below the webcam display.

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <video onclick="snapshot(this);" width=400 height=400 id="video" controller autoplay></video>
        <button type="button" onclick="startWebcam();" style="background-color: #3c8dbc;border-color: #367fa9;color: #fff;border:0;height:30px;" >START WEBCAM</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="stopWebcam();" style="background-color: #3c8dbc;border-color: #367fa9;color: #fff;border:0;height:30px;" >STOP WEBCAM</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="snapshot();" id="snapShot" class="snapShot" style="background-color: #3c8dbc;border-color: #367fa9;color: #fff;border:0;height:30px;" >TAKE SNAPSHOT</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="savePicture"  style="background-color: #3c8dbc;border-color: #367fa9;color: #fff;border:0;height:30px;" >SAVE PICTURE</button> -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="container" style="overflow: hidden;width: 200px;"> 
        <div id="inner" style="  overflow: hidden;  width: 200px;">
        
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current JS code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var video;
   var webcamStream;
   var clicks = 0;

   function startWebcam() {
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia (

          // constraints
          {
             video: true,
             audio: false
          },

          // successCallback
         function(localMediaStream) {
              video = document.querySelector('video');
             //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
             video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
             webcamStream = localMediaStream;
             video.play();
         },

          // errorCallback
         function(err) {
             console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
         }
       );
    } else {
       console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
    }
  }

  function snapshot() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, 0,0, 640, 480);        

    clicks += 1;
    
    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = '';
    
    for (x=0; x < clicks; x++)
    {               
                              
        $(document).ready(function() { $('#inner').append('<div id="div-'+x+'" style="background-color: #fff;float: left; width: 250px;height: 250px;"><canvas id="canvas'+x+'" width="640" height="480"></canvas></div>'); });               
        
        var canvasx = document.getElementById("canvas"+x);
        var contextx = canvasx.getContext('2d');
        contextx.drawImage(video, 0,0, 100, 100);
        
        console.log(contextx);
    }     

  }

 </script>
```

How do I have a previous image(s) stay and have a new image to be displayed next to the old image(s)?  Right now, it shows different canvases, however, it shows the same image each time.

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

The problem was within was that the canvas wasn't an array. So here is what I had to do.

First I had to create the canvas into an array:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),img, i, image_array = [];
```

Then I got the canvas into an url:

```
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
```

I push the image url into the image array:

```
    image_array.push(dataURL);
```

Now I did I created a for loop:

```
     for (i = 0; i < image_array.length; i++) {  
      img = new Image();  
      img.src = image_array[i];  
      img.onload = (function(img, i){ 
      return function () {                         
           $(document).ready(function() { $('#inner').append('<div id="divimage" style="background-color: #fff;float: left; width: 300px;height: 300px;"><img style="width:250px; height:250px;" src="'+img.src+'" /></canvas></div>'); });                  
       }  
     })(img, i);
  }
```

This solved my problem.